# Word order in passive

Tags: word-order

Archaeologists have discovered a new tomb in Egypt.

> 1. A new tomb in Egypt has been discovered by archaeologists.
> 2. A new tomb has been discovered in Egypt by archaeologists.

Which word order is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Either word order is correct.  It simply depends on whether you wish to emphasise that **a new tomb** has been discovered, or you wish to emphasise that **a new tomb in Egypt** has been discovered.

You could also have said:

> In Egypt, a new tomb has been discovered by archaeologists.

if you only wanted to emphasise that this event took place in Egypt.